# How to use a variabe inside a python command?

Tags: python, variables

I'm using a framework to retrieve values of my drone's parameters. One of the command I would like to use is vehicle.parameters
When I use

```
vehicle.parameters['GPS_TO_INJECT']
```

It works well and prints me 127.0. Now I want to include this in a function, so If I use:

```
def change_value():
    a = GPS_TO_INJECT
    vehicle.parameters['a']
```

It does not work, printing me:

> a =GPS_INJECT_TO NameError: global name 'GPS_INJECT_TO' is not defined

What is wrong with it?

Comment: You are using the string "a", not the variable. Remove the quotes.

Comment: you haven't passed that variable to function

Comment: You do not store the value as a string, so it tries to read it as a varible. Because it does not exist as a variable. try `"GPS_TO_INJECT"`

Comment: @Mark error is for the first line as `GPS_TO_INJECT` unknown to him

Comment: `vehicle.parameters['GPS_TO_INJECT']` Is not a command. Did you mean, perhaps, `vehicle.parameters('GPS_TO_INJECT')`

Answer (score 3):

First, define `a` with the string `GPS_TO_INJECT`, second type variable `a` as a key for `vehicle.parameters`.

```
def change_value():
    a = 'GPS_TO_INJECT'
    vehicle.parameters[a]
```

As you did in your first example, you have passed `GPS_TO_INJECT` as a string to `vehicle.parameters`, same you need in your second section of code.

Answer (score 0):

The a is a variable while 'a' is a string. Thus what you are passing is not the variable.

Also, the GPS_INJECT_TO is undefined. It is recognized as a global constant rather then string.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value **GPS_TO_INJECT** to variable **a** in the following way:

```
a = "GPS_TO_INJECT"
```

Once done, then try to access the vehicle.parameters value as:

```
print vehicle.parameters[a]
```

For Python 3 write:

```
print(vehicle.parameters[a])
```